# Extraer dos ultimos carcteres de una cadena

Tags: visual-studio, string, vb, caracteres, substring

para poder extraer los dos últimos caracteres de una cadena ingresada por teclado, conviene usar substring?? Si saben de alguna forma, avisen porfavor. 
Esto mismo para el lenguaje de visual basic net.

Answer (score 1):

Con la función `RIGHT` lo tienes sencillo

```
RIGHT(cadena, 2)
```

Dónde *cadena* es un string

Comment: Excelente! Muchas graciass